# Do search engines see a "webpage.xml" file as xml? How does that impact microdata?

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf, microdata, rdfa

A website I'm working on uses xml files for each page (rather than php or html files). The xml is converted to html (soon html5) via xslt on the client side. I intend to make these pages usefully semantic and I was interested in how search engines see the page.

Since a human on the site sees the URL as "www.example.com/webpage.xml", I assume that the page is being processed by search engines as xml too, rather than the result of the xslt conversion. Is this true?

If this is true, do I even care about html5 microdata? Would I instead be adding semantics to my xml document? What language(s) would be appropriate for this?

Finally, what about the meta tags in the head of html pages? Do I not care about those either as they'd result from the xslt and would therefore be ignored?

I hope that all seems logical.

Thanks,

Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

```
The xml is converted to html (soon html5) via xslt
```

Is the convertion done on server side? If so, the search engine must see the generated html with all meta-data. You should check the http response with Firebug tool for example.

Comment: Thanks for your question. The conversion is done client side. I'll update the original question.

Comment: In this case you could try to use google crawling agreement for dynamic apps: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: No dis-respect but having done some more research, it feels like this is moving in the wrong direction. It seems that something like RDF or RDFa should allow me to embed information directly into the xml or help make the existing information within the XML interpretable by the search engines. Perhaps I'm wrong.